# Access local variables from a closure

Tags: gradle, groovy, closures

I'm trying to do something like this

```
def myFunc(Closure config) {
  def var1
  def var2

  config()

  println var1, var2
}

myFunc {
  var1 = "hello"
  var2 = "world"
}
```

Is there a way to make this work? Delegates only work for class fields, and not for local vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy script does one thing when it comes to reading values of a given property - when it exists in current scope (local variable, object's field etc.) it uses its value, otherwise it refers to `binding` object which holds all bindings that are not variables, fields etc.

What happens in your case is the following:

```
myFunc {
  var1 = "hello"
  var2 = "world"
}
```

When this closure gets executed it adds `var1` and `var2` to a `binding` with corresponding values. When `myFunc` gets executed:

```
def myFunc(Closure config) {
  def var1
  def var2

  config()

  println var1
  println var2
}
```

it does not use `binding` to read values for `var1` and `var2`, because in current scope both variable exist and that is why

```
null
null
```

gets printed.

But if you change the way you read `var1` and `var2` after `config()` to something like this:

```
def myFunc(Closure config) {
  def var1
  def var2

  config()

  println binding.getVariable("var1") ?: var1
  println binding.getVariable("var2") ?: var2
}
```

you will explicitly check if `config()` added `var1` and `var2` to a `binding` and if it's true you will read the value modified by the executed closure. Otherwise you will read local default values for `var1` and `var2`.

```
hello
world
```

This is similar to removing local variables from `myFunc` and calling a closure like:

```
def myFunc(Closure config) {
  config()

  println var1
  println var2
}
```

But in this case you are referring to `binding` only and there is no place for a local variables to being involved in the process. I'm guessing that you have to deal with existing local variables and you can't just remove them - in this case being explicit about reading `binding` or local variable is the best way to handle it.

### Gradle case

In case of running into such situation in `build.gradle` script you can use a popular approach with using map object delegate, so all variables used inside the closure get automatically assigned as a map properties. Consider following example:

```
def myFunc(Closure config) {
  def var1
  def var2

  def map = [:]
  config.delegate = map
  config.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  config()

  println map.getOrDefault('var1', var1)
  println map.getOrDefault('var2', var2)
}

task hello {
  doLast {
    myFunc {
      var1 = "hello"
      var2 = "world"
    }
  }
}
```

In this case running `myFunc` with given closure ends with assigning `var1` and `var2` properties on a delegated map object. It gives us an opportunity to use `map.getOrDefault(key,default)` method to retrieve a value set with the closure or use the default local variable value.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the interesting insight about how the groovy works, but as I mentioned in a previous answer, I get an error `unknown property 'var1'` in both cases. Perhaps I should have mentioned that this is all happening inside gradle build script, it seems the behavior is different from the vanilla groovy.

Comment: @Morse can you show an example based on your `build.gradle`? It will help reproducing your problem.

Comment: This pretty much is the example. The call for the function is inside the doLast section of some task, that's all.

Comment: @Morse Got it. I've updated the answer with a solution that works in Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the variables as shown below?

```
def myFunc(Closure config) {  
  config()    
  println var1
  println var2
}

myFunc {   
  var1 = "hello"   
  var2 = "world" 
}
```

Comment: Actually, I get an error `unknown property 'var1'` in both cases. Perhaps I should have mentioned that this is all happening inside gradle build script, it seems the behavior is different from the vanilla groovy.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I use gradle 2.14.1